# Is it possible to have auditd log different rules in different log files?

Tags: linux-audit

I would like to have some rules logged in a file that is not the default log file defined in `/etc/audit/auditd.conf`. Is there a way to have auditd log some rules in a separate file?

Something like `-w /tmp -LOGFILE /var/log/someother/location/log`?

Comment: Yes, in the worst case by hacking the source code. Can you be a bit more specific, such as including how you want to filter?

Comment: well I have a set of rules for tracking files. But I also want to use auditd to map processes being cloned from some applications on the system using the `-S clone` rule. I would like to have that in a separate file as those are not really logs and more of an input for a script